# How Can I create a comma separated string in sql for CHOOSE function?

Tags: sql-server, database, csv

I use `SQL Server 2012`
I want use `Chosse` Function Is SQL Server and I need get values for second argument from 
un other table in Database.

```
Create Table Person
(
    Id Int identity(1,1),
    Name NVarchar(10),
    Sex int
)
Insert Into Person values ('ss',1)
Insert Into Person values ('s',2)
Insert Into Person values ('d',2)
Insert Into Person values ('f',1)
Insert Into Person values ('g',2)
Insert Into Person values ('h',1)

Create Table Value1
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Name NvarChar(200),
    Val int
)

Insert InTo Value1 Values ('Homme',1)
Insert Into Value1 values ('Famme',2)

Select 
    Id , Name ,
    CHOOSE( Sex , 
            (
                SELECT 
                    STUFF(
                            (
                                SELECT ',' + V.Name
                                FROM value1 As V
                                ORDER BY V.Name
                                FOR XML PATH('')
                            )
                            ,1,1,''
                        ) AS CSV
            )
         ) 
From Person


Drop Table value1
```

Comment: If you have a table the the different values for sex why go through the trouble of using choose and the xml thing? Why not join it directly? Or maybe this is just a simplified example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to do something not possible through the `CHOOSE` function. It is meant to provide a dynamic index to a manually static array you define within the statement. Even with the CSV list generating through the XML PATH, you are only providing a single element to the CHOOSE (only referenced by 1 and anything higher showing the NULL value).  There is no way to provide a dynamic list of values. Perhaps one of the 2 methods below can meet what you are trying to achieve.

```
-- Join directly on val
SELECT P.Id, P.Name, V.Name
FROM Person P
    INNER JOIN Value1 V
        ON P.Sex = V.Val

-- Use ROW_NUMBER to provide an index to join sex to the same index that your choose is attempting
SELECT P.Id, P.Name, V.Name
FROM Person P
    INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS Id, Name FROM Value1) V
        ON P.Sex = V.Id
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213019(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As others said direct join should do the job. 
The problem with your code is choose function needs a index and a list of CSV.

In your case the CSV will be like `CHOOSE(Sex ,'Homme,Famme')` but actually it needs something like this `CHOOSE(Sex'Homme','Famme')`

So what happened is the entire string is considered like a single value. so for only sex=1 it returned values.

And still you want to do with choose function means then this may help you. Declare @homme and  @famme variable with varchar type

```
SELECT @Homme = Name
FROM   #Value1
WHERE  Name = 'Homme'

SELECT @Famme = Name
FROM   #Value1
WHERE  Name = 'Famme'

SELECT Id,
       Name,
       Choose(Sex, @Homme, @Famme)
FROM   #Person
```